# Can't get any kind of smoothscroll working

Tags: html, smooth-scrolling

I've been trying to figure out why I can't get any kind of smoothscroll to work for a few hours now and just can't find/see the issue.

I have included below my entire html, including the jquery. the smoothscroll I used was this one:

https://paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery

Any help would be greatly appreciated

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Lora|Montserrat|Open+Sans|PT+Sans|Roboto|Source+Sans+Pro|Noto+Serif|Droid+Serif" rel="stylesheet">

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

       <div id="wrappernav">

            <ul class="navbar">
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="work.html">WORK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#flexcontact">LETS CHAT</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    <section class="flexheader">

    <div class="windmillcontainer">

        <img class="windmill" alt="" src="image/windmill.png">

        <img class="island" alt="" src="image/island.png">

    </div>

    </section>

    <section class="bodycontainer">

        <div class="flexbody">

            <img class="portrait" alt="" src="image/portrait.png">

            <h1>Hello!</h1>

            <p> My name is Andrew McCaughey, I love creating strange and quirky designs like this website...</p>

            <hr>

            <p class="p2">I'm a graphic designer / web developer based in Belfast, Northern Ireland. I have a passion for graphic and web design, I love to create websites, logos and illustrations.</p>

        </div>

    </section>

    <section class="contactcontainer">

        <div id="flexcontact">

        <h2>Lets Chat!</h2>

            <p class="contactp">I’m currently available for freelance work.</p>

            <hr>

            <p class="contactp2">If you have a project that you want to get started, think you need my help with something or just fancy saying hey, then get in touch.</p>

            <a id="buttona" href="mailto:"><img id="button" alt="" src="image/button.jpg"></a>

        </div>

    </section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});    

    </script>   


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that code is a few years old, check out this one. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: I appreciate the link but I have already tried that one aswell and it isn't working, i've tried atleast 5 different smoothscroll options and couldn't get any of them to work.

Comment: Is your code above from the link you posted? Can you give me a link to your site with that code on it?

Comment: @Zecele can you explain which part is not working? I have tried your code in jsfiddle and it seems working fine (I suppose the scrolling part is not work). can you check the developer console and see whether there is an error or not?

Comment: The issue is it jumps too the contact section instead of smooth scrolling. I can't see any errors in the developer console but i'll put the website on github and link it below.

Comment: https://github.com/AndrewMC1994/Portfolio